# Change innerHTML from an external php file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I've got a script in an `HTML` file that runs a `php` file every 30 seconds. The `php` file is intended to change a div's innerHTML. I don't seem to find the way to replace it.

I was using `load()` but there are several `div`s I want to keep updating every 30 seconds and I don't want to make the server GET that much requests. So I'm looking for one only `php` get and then change the innerhtml in those several divs

This is what i've got:

`HTML`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('php.php');
});
setInterval(function(){
    $.get('php.php');
}, 30000);
</script>

<div id="foo"></div>
```

`php.php`:

```
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = '<?php
// some php code
 ?>';
```

I think the problem is I'm not being able to get the element from the parent `HTML` file. I don't know how to solve this...
Any suggestions will be more than aprecciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reinventing jQuery's [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
function fetchContent() {
     $("#foo").load('php.php');
     window.setTimeout(fetchContent, 30000);
}
$(fetchContent);
```

The server should just return the HTML content that you want to display.

---

EDIT

Since your comment is different from the original question.

```
function fetchContent() {
     $("#foo").get('php.php', function(data) {
         var html = $("<div/>").html(data);             
         $("#foo").html( html.find("#Section1").html() );
         $("#bar").html( html.find("#Section2").html() );
         $("#asd").html( html.find("#Section3").html() );
         window.setTimeout(fetchContent, 30000);
     });
}
$(fetchContent);
```

You would want to add an onError handler and might want to set the no cache option for the Ajax calls.

Comment: Kind of... I was using `load()` but there are several `div`s I want to keep updating every 30 seconds and I don't want to make the server GET that much requests. So I'm looking for one only `php` get and then change the innerhtml in those several divs

Comment: It would help if that was in your info from the start!

Answer (score 1):

what you probably want is for your php.php to return some data, and then you use the success of the $.get to update your #foo; taking an example from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ and modifying it for your example

```
$.get("php.php", function( data ) {
    $( '#foo' ).html( data );
});
```

hope that helps :)

Comment: I can't quite understand what you say... I'm knew to coding. I'm trying to print the following inside the div `document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = '<? $line1= file_get_contents('example/foo.txt'); print htmlentities($line1);?>';`

Comment: I don't know how to export the data `$line1` to use in the function

Comment: I updated the question with more information about my problem. Maybe now you can help me? ;)

Comment: Sorry for not replying, I was offline shortly after putting an answer, my bad.